# Plotting Asia session high and low

Tags: session, pine-script

I’m trying to plot the Asia range (0000-0400) with dashed lines in my tradingview chart by using pinescript. So far no luck.

What does it need to do:

Plot the session high and low within the Asia session (0000-0400)

I would like to know your insights.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Search `FXN session indicator` and add to your chart.